# How to view image in solid mode in 2.8

Tags: image

Hello I have an image I am trying to use as a reference, but it only appears as a solid color in solid mode and only shows the actual image in render or lookdev. How do I make the image visible in solid mode where I do all of the modeling?

I already have it in front and have tried dragging the clip threshold up and down to no avail so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I actually just figured it out. Go to the shading dropdown to the right of all the shaders then select texture as the color.

Comment: Good to know, I totally forgot about this feature :).

Comment: does this apply in wireframe as well